# Cross-validating H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator?

Tags: cross-validation, h2o

[H2O docs claim](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html) that "for all algos that support the nfolds parameter" cross-validation is done by the `train` method.

However, [`H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html) does not:

> H2OValueError: Unknown parameter nfolds = 5

So, how do I cross-validate such a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the CV parameter for Stacked Ensemble is called `metalearner_nfolds` instead of `nfolds`.  This is to emphasize that the cross-validation is for the metalearning algorithm.  The list of parameters for Stacked Ensemble can be found [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html).

Comment: Thanks! Then why does `cross_validation_metrics_summary` print `No cross-validation metrics summary for this model` even though the printed representation of the stacked ensemble includes `** Reported on cross-validation data. **`?

Comment: @sds No reason other than the print statement is not implemented.  There's a ticket open here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3911. You can print the `cross_validation_metrics_summary` for the metalearner model stored inside the Stacked Ensemble model, however.

Comment: How do I extract those numbers for further processing?